# Can we use Firebase as backend for a Wordpress website?

Tags: wordpress, firebase, web-applications, backend

I am aware of the plugin at 
https://itnext.io/how-to-integrate-firebase-and-wordpress-b017ee274687

The problem is it does not have full functionality to read databases, and perform authentication, run cloud functions, etc.

Is there any other better way that i am unable to find, or has this problem never been solved yet, for easy-to-implement solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

there is a guide for Firebase WordPress Integration for the PRO plugin.

https://firebase-wordpress-docs.readthedocs.io

Which issue are you trying to solve with Firebase and WordPress?